# How to fix: java: not a statement, and other errors

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and I need to create a two dimensional array of boolean of which the dimensions of can be changed and then display the boolean table, but I am getting some errors.

I tried using the reccomended fixes but these made more errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner joos = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired height of the grid.");
        int y = joos.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired width of the grid.");
        int x = joos.nextInt();
        boolean [] [] height = new boolean[y][x];
        //System.out.println(y);
        //System.out.println(x);
        int i = 0;
        int j = y*x;

        for (i<=j:i++;) {
            System.out.println(height[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (i<=j:i++;)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: [Java `for` statement tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: It would be helpful if, in addition to the sample code, that you included the actual errors. People who are familiar with the error message format would immediately be able to spot that particular error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things going on here:
First, the statement `for(i<=j; i++;)` is not a valid way to create a `for` loop.  Secondly, if `i<j`, but `j=x*y`, then you are going to get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you call `height[i]` when `i>=y`.

If you want to do something for each position in your 2d array, you can use the following nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        // do something now with the boolean at height[i][j]
        boolean value = height[i][j];
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

The general idea here is that a 2d array requires a "2d" loop (in other words, 2 nested loops) to access each element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help but now I was wondering how to display them as a grid. Currently it prints false in a line but is there a way to print them in the 2d shape?